# How do I install and build fovis_ros?

Tags: ros, fovis, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm attempting to install and use fovis_ros, and I feel as though I'm missing something. I did the following in a top-level ROS workspace:

> cd /src

> sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-fovis

Apparently there's no binary package so I did a

> > git clone https://github.com/srv/fovis.git

This created

/src/fovis

> /fovis

> /fovis_ros

Then,

> catkin_make

and I got

"The specified source space "/home/blah-blah-my-dirs/src/fovis/src" does not exist"

And indeed, ./fovis/fovis/src does not exist.

Reading [here](http://wiki.ros.org/fovis), I see "This stack contains two packages: libfovis and fovis_ros. The former contains a Makefile for downloading and building fovis, the latter contains the ROS wrapper for this library."

I was expecting that doing catkin_make would automagically go get libfovis and build it, but no soap.

Is this a bug, or a feature? :)

Thanks,

Rick

P.S. I also tried

> sudo apt-get install libfovis,

and this installed fine, but still didn't help with building fovis_ros.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163561/how-do-i-install-and-build-fovis_ros?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-10-27**:
I have the same problem after install libfovis.

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/libfovis/cmake/libfovisConfig.cmake:141 (message):
Project 'fovis_ros' tried to find library 'libfovis'.  The library is
neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
'libfovis'?

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-10-28**:
Hi Lili,

It's been a while, but if I remember correctly,

1. pulling the Miquel's latest libfovis drop as of May 11 (see below), and
2. building libfovis in the top level of my ROS workspace fixed my problem.

Rick

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-10-29**:
Thanks a lot! It has been successfully compiled! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Rick,

could you please try putting ros-hydro-libfovis? If that does not work try instead downloading libfovis in your ws from https://github.com/srv/libfovis
There may be something wrong with the debian package.

Can you please tell me which ROS distro are you using?

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-05-11**:
Miquel, I'm using hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I installed ros-hydro-libfovis but fovis_ros still didn't find libfovis. I then downloaded the libfovis source to my ws as you suggested, and this fixed the problem. Next issue: compiling mono_depth_odometer.cpp fails, unable to find fovis_ros/FovisInfo.h

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-05-11**:
Also: thanks!

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-05-11**:
I added a message generation dependency to fovis_ros. Please update your package -> git pull. Good catch!

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-05-12**:
That did the trick, thanks!